# Sort and print sequentially keys and values from a nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, loops, sorting, dictionary

This my first question here. I am learning how to manipulate  dictionaries in Python. But I am facing a challenge.

I have a nested dictionary of soccer matches. Each subdictionary is a match betteween two teams and its corresponding number of goals.
I need to print the results of each match, sorting each team alphabetically. Additionally, the next step is to print the results of the following

match, but also including the results of the previous match, keeping all teams of sorted alphabetically.

Here is an example:

```
soccer = {
    1 : {"England": 2, "Poland": 3},
    2 : {"Italy": 2, "Sweeden": 0},
    3 : {"Spain": 2, "Belgium": 2}
}
```

The output should be like this:

```
Points Scored After Match 1

England: 0 points
Poland: 3 points


Points Scored After Match 2

England: 0 points
Italy: 3 points
Poland: 3 points
Sweeden: 0 points


Points Scored After Match 3

Belgium: 1 point
England: 0 points
Italy: 3 points
Poland: 3 points
Spain: 1 point
Sweeden: 0 points
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have posted here are the requirements. What have you coded up for these requirements? Show us your work and where you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example how to sort keys/values in dictionary and format the items for print function:

```
soccer={1:{"England":2,"Poland":3}, 2:{"Italy":2, "Sweeden":0}, 3:{"Spain":2, "Belgium":2}}

points = {}
for match_no, match in sorted(soccer.items(), key=lambda k: k[0]):
    team_1, team_2 = match.keys()
    score_1, score_2 = match.values()

    if score_1 == score_2:
        points[team_1] = points.get(team_1, 0) + 1
        points[team_2] = points.get(team_2, 0) + 1
    elif score_1 > score_2:
        points[team_1] = points.get(team_1, 0) + 3
        points[team_2] = points.get(team_2, 0) + 0
    else:
        points[team_1] = points.get(team_1, 0) + 0
        points[team_2] = points.get(team_2, 0) + 3

    # print results:
    print()
    print('Points Scored After Match {}'.format(match_no))
    print()

    for team, p in sorted(points.items(), key=lambda k: k[0]):
        print('{}: {} point{}'.format(team, p, '' if p == 1 else 's'))
```

Prints:

```
Points Scored After Match 1

England: 0 points
Poland: 3 points

Points Scored After Match 2

England: 0 points
Italy: 3 points
Poland: 3 points
Sweeden: 0 points

Points Scored After Match 3

Belgium: 1 point
England: 0 points
Italy: 3 points
Poland: 3 points
Spain: 1 point
Sweeden: 0 points
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
soccer={1:{"England":2,"Poland":3}, 2:{"Italy":2, "Sweeden":0}, 3:{"Spain":2, "Belgium":2}}
points={"England":0,"Poland":0,"Italy":0, "Sweeden":0,"Spain":0, "Belgium":0}
for match_number in soccer:
    for country in soccer[match_number]:
        team_one, team_two = soccer[match_number].keys()
        score_one, score_two = soccer[match_number].values()
        if score_one > score_two:
            points[team_one] = points.get(team_one) + 3
        if score_one < score_two:
            points[team_two] = points.get(team_two) + 3
        if score_one == score_two:
            points[team_one] = points.get(team_one) + 1
            points[team_two] = points.get(team_two) + 1
        print("Points scored after: ", match_number)
        for key in points:
            print(key,points[key])
```

It outputs this:

```
Points scored after:  1
England 0
Poland 3
Italy 0
Sweeden 0
Spain 0
Belgium 0
Points scored after:  1
England 0
Poland 6
Italy 0
Sweeden 0
Spain 0
Belgium 0
Points scored after:  2
England 0
Poland 6
Italy 3
Sweeden 0
Spain 0
Belgium 0
Points scored after:  2
England 0
Poland 6
Italy 6
Sweeden 0
Spain 0
Belgium 0
Points scored after:  3
England 0
Poland 6
Italy 6
Sweeden 0
Spain 1
Belgium 1
Points scored after:  3
England 0
Poland 6
Italy 6
Sweeden 0
Spain 2
Belgium 2
```

Next time try posting your attempt at the problem too. Cheers!